# How can I put a ForeignKey field in alphabetical order?

Tags: python, django

this is my code.

models.py

```
class Preventivo(models.Model):
    prestazione1 = models.ForeignKey('Prestazione',on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="prestazione1")
```

form.py

```
class PreventivoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Preventivo
        fields = ['cliente','prestazione1']
```

[image: my form]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine the field to give it a custom queryset that's ordered how you want.

```
class PreventivoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    prestazione1 = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=Prestazione.objects.order_by('name'))

    class Meta:
        model = Preventivo
        fields = ['cliente','prestazione1']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it in the `__init__` method of your `ModelForm`.
This comes in handy if you need to pass other information to the `Form`, which you can then read from the kwargs.

```
class PreventivoForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Preventivo
        fields = ['cliente','prestazione1']

 def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['prestazione1'].queryset = Preventivo.objects.order_by('<FIELDNAME>')
```

Comment: You don't actually need to do that in the init, you can redefine the field at class level. But why have you added "user" into the init signature?